# php8 FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, php-8, php-8.2

I upgrade php version from 7.4 to 8.2 but I found error when I launch application :

> [proxy:error] [pid 13] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*:80) failed

this is code dockerfile:

```
######
### General Base Install
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.2
###

# Install Apache
RUN yum install -y httpd \
&& groupmod -g 2000 apache \
&& usermod -u 2000 apache \
# Install tools
&& yum install -y nano zip unzip cronie procps bzip2 curl \
# Install PHP 8.2
&& amazon-linux-extras install php${PHP_VERSION} \
&& yum install -y php-common php-json php-cli php-fpm php-pdo php-pgsql php-mbstring php-opcache \
# Install PgSQL Client
# && amazon-linux-extras install -y postgresql11 \
# Install Xdebug and dependencies, disabled by default
&& yum install -y php-process php-xml php-pear php-devel php-pecl-xdebug php${PHP_VERSION}-fpm php${PHP_VERSION}-cli gcc make \
#&& pecl install /tmp/xdebug-3.1.1.tgz \
#&& rm /tmp/xdebug-3.1.1.tgz \
&& echo ";zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so" > /etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini \

######
### Finalize Install

# Allow FPM to Read Env Var like Docker Env ;)
RUN sed -i 's/;clear_env/clear_env/' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
# Define working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/

COPY default.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80 8089
######
### Launch
COPY entrypoint.sh /root
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/root/entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

file www.sock not found in /var/run but when i put php-fpm -v i found 8.2

file www.sock not found in /var/run but when i put php-fpm -v i found 8.2